# How to print a single specified element of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Using the Array.getDouble() Method I can print the entire array but I cant figure out how to just print one element. 
ie. if I just wanted to print index 20, how would I do that?

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class freq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Declaring Array */
        /** English letter frequencies */
   double a[] = {
        0.0855, 0.0160, 0.0316, 0.0387, 0.1210,
        0.0218, 0.0209, 0.0496, 0.0733, 0.0022,
        0.0081, 0.0421, 0.0253, 0.0717, 0.0747,
        0.0207, 0.0010, 0.0633, 0.0673, 0.0894,
        0.0268, 0.0106, 0.0183, 0.0019, 0.0172,
        0.0011
    }; 

    /* Traversing the array */
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {

        /* Array.getDouble() Method */
        double x = (double)Array.getDouble(a, j);

        /* Print Values */
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
    }
}
```

I get the output:

0.0855 0.0160 0.0316 0.0387 0.1210 0.0218 0.0209 0.0496 0.0733 0.0022 0.0081 0.0421 0.0253 0.0717 0.0747 0.0207 0.0010 0.0633 0.0673 0.0894 0.0268 0.0106 0.0183 0.0019 0.0172 0.0011

I want to get the output of (for example)
 c = 0.0316

Comment: you use loop a statement "for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)" ... if you want to get print only one item please double x = (double)Array.getDouble(a, 20); System.out.print(x + " ");

Comment: what about `System.out.println(a[20])`

Comment: Just remove your for-Loop and put j = 20 or just print out a[20]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: why are you using `Array.getDouble`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
public class freq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double a[] = {
            0.0855, 0.0160, 0.0316, 0.0387, 0.1210,
            0.0218, 0.0209, 0.0496, 0.0733, 0.0022,
            0.0081, 0.0421, 0.0253, 0.0717, 0.0747,
            0.0207, 0.0010, 0.0633, 0.0673, 0.0894,
            0.0268, 0.0106, 0.0183, 0.0019, 0.0172,
            0.0011
        }; 
        System.out.println("c = " + a[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is a lot simpler than I anticipated & exactly the output I want.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need the Array call. You can simplify it like this:

```java
public class Freq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Declaring Array */
        /** English letter frequencies */
   double a[] = {
        0.0855, 0.0160, 0.0316, 0.0387, 0.1210,
        0.0218, 0.0209, 0.0496, 0.0733, 0.0022,
        0.0081, 0.0421, 0.0253, 0.0717, 0.0747,
        0.0207, 0.0010, 0.0633, 0.0673, 0.0894,
        0.0268, 0.0106, 0.0183, 0.0019, 0.0172,
        0.0011
    };

    /* Traversing the array */
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
        System.out.println(a[j] + " ");
    }

    int index = 20;
    System.out.println(index + " = " + a[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* Declaring Array */
    char[] alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray(); // alphabets array
    /** English letter frequencies */
    double a[] = {
    0.0855, 0.0160, 0.0316, 0.0387, 0.1210,
    0.0218, 0.0209, 0.0496, 0.0733, 0.0022,
    0.0081, 0.0421, 0.0253, 0.0717, 0.0747,
    0.0207, 0.0010, 0.0633, 0.0673, 0.0894,
    0.0268, 0.0106, 0.0183, 0.0019, 0.0172,
    0.0011
}; 

/* Traversing the array */
for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {

    /* Array.getDouble() Method */
    double x = (double)Array.getDouble(a, j);

    /* Print Values */
    System.out.print( alpha[i]+" = "x + " "); // value for corresponding alphabets
}
}
}
```

All you need is to declare alphabets `array char[] alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();` and `System.out.print( alpha[i+1]+" = "x + " ");`

Hope this helps. Happy Coding <3 !

Thanks